# How to make multiplyList work? Haskell ref: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Lists_II

Tags: haskell

I am exercising the `multiplyList` function that uses `applyToIntegers` in GHCi.  I want it to multiply a list by 2. Below is what I tried and the error I got. Below that, for convenience, is an excerpt from Lists II.

The code in Lists II compiles OK. My problem is: where do I put the multiplier in the code?

I can use `applyToIntegers` by itself OK, and I can duplicate what it does using `map`. I just can't make the connection from `multiplyList` to `applyToIntgers`.

This is my first post as I am learning Haskell (which I had never heard of before last month!) from the excellent Haskell wikibook, and I must say that Haskell is the most beautiful high-level programming language I've ever encountered.

```
applyToIntegers :: (Integer -> Integer) -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
applyToIntegers _ [] = []
applyToIntegers f (n:ns) = (f n) : applyToIntegers f ns
-- E.g., applyToIntegers (2*) [1..5] = [2,4,6,8,10], also
-–  map (2*) [1..5] = [2,4,6,8,10]

-- Unable to come up with a working example:
multiplyList :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
--multiplyList m = applyToIntegers ((*) m) -- Compiles OK.
-- If I try:
multiplyList m = applyToIntegers ((2*) m)
```

I get the following:

```
*Main> :l ods.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ods.hs, interpreted )

ods.hs:15:35: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer -> Integer’
                  with actual type ‘Integer’
    • Possible cause: ‘2 *’ is applied to too many arguments
      In the first argument of ‘applyToIntegers’, namely ‘((2 *) m)’
      In the expression: applyToIntegers ((2 *) m)
      In an equation for ‘multiplyList’:
      multiplyList m = applyToIntegers ((2 *) m)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
```

---

https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=Haskell/Lists_II&oldid=3242682

> We need a function that takes any other appropriate function and applies the
>       given function to the elements of a list:
>
> ```
> applyToIntegers :: (Integer -> Integer) -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
> applyToIntegers _ [] = []
> applyToIntegers f (n:ns) = (f n) : applyToIntegers f ns
> ```
>
> With `applyToIntegers`, we can take any `Integer -> Integer` function and apply 
>       it to the elements of a list of Integers. We can thus use this generalized 
>       function to redefine multiplyList:
>
> ```
> multiplyList :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
> multiplyList m = applyToIntegers ((*) m)
> ```
>
> That uses the `(*)` function with a single initial argument to create a new 
>       function which is ready to take one more argument (which, in this use case, 
>       will come from the numbers in a given list).

Comment: You question might look a little better if you removed that URL from the title and instead put it in the question body, as an actual clickable link

Comment: You've got the answer right there. You've applied `(*)` to too many arguments, as the error states. Replace `m` with `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type signature of multiplyList:

`Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]`

says it takes an integer, a list of integers, and it returns a list of integers.

Therefore, multiplyList is intended to take the parameter to multiply the list by.

If we want to multiply by 2, using the definition of multiplyList:

`multiplyList m = applyToIntegers ((*) m)`

we can just call `multiplyList 2 [1..3] == [2,4,6]`.

It's a bit easier to demonstrate how multiplyList works if we simply the definition to

`multiplyList n xs = applyToIntegers (\x -> x * n) xs`.

This is exactly the same as the previous definition, just written in a way which you might find easier to understand.

This says that multiplyList takes an integer `n`, and a list `xs`, and passes a function which multiplies by `n`, and the list `xs` to applyToIntegers.

`applyToIntegers` then applies that multiply function to every item in the list.

In conclusion, you simply need to call `multiplyList` with the value to multiply by. We could separate this into a separate function, if you like:

`multiplyListByTwo xs = multiplyList 2 xs`

which can be eta reduced to `multiplyListByTwo = multiplyList 2`

We can then use this function on any list, and the values will be multiplied by 2.

`multiplyListByTwo [1..3]` would give `[2,4,6]`.

Comment: The utter simplicity of your answer put a big smile on my face! Many thanks to all who responded.

Answer (score 1):

let's take a look at both functions definition

```
applyToIntegers :: (Integer -> Integer) -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
multiplyList :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
```

now the return type of functions are the some [Integer] . now

```
multiplyList m = applyToIntegers ((2*) m)
```

starting from right to left we see that applyToIntegers require 2 argument but given 1 . the expression inside () is calculate and then returned as result.

```
multiplyList m = applyToIntegers (2*) m
```

in this point we now the type m is [Integer] and multiplyList require one argument not 2 rewriting the definition for multiplyList

```
multiplyList ::[Integer] -> [Integer]
```

result :

```
applyToIntegers :: (Integer -> Integer) -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
applyToIntegers _ [] = []
applyToIntegers f (n:ns) = (f n) : applyToIntegers f ns

multiplyList :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
multiplyList m = applyToIntegers ((2*) m)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all about currying. `(*)` is a function with signature `Integer -> Integer -> Integer`. `((*) 2)` generates a function with signature `Integer -> Integer`, that you can apply to a second number and get a product. This function is provided to `applyToIntegers` to produce a function `multiplyList` that will take a list as an argument. You could also see `multiplyList` as a function that takes two arguments, `m`, which is a number (e.g. 2), and a list.

So the compiler message is pretty on the spot, it's telling you `applyToIntegers` expected a function ((*) 2), but you provided a number (2*m). You must call it like

`multiplyList 2 [1,2,3]`

Just like in the previous example in the book chapter. This same function is just being rewritten in another way, where the arguments become implicit, "higher-order" style...

Comment: Although it doesn't show, I did register a "like" for this answer.  It is helping me wrap my head around how Haskell can get the missing integer from the left hand side of the equation as an argument in multiplyList  which looks to me as though it takes only one argument , namely,  "m".

Comment: Every function in Haskell actually "takes one argument", and returns potentially another function that will take another argument. So you can think of `multiplyList` either as function taking one number and returning a function that takes a list, or as a function that takes a number and a list. Partial application is Haskell's bread and butter.